# EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ef-core-3.0, hierarchyid

In my .NetCore3 project, I use HierarchyId to implement data tree structure. 
I am successful in storing as a tree, But I have trouble getting children.

**MyModel :**

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public HierarchyId Level { get; set; }
```

[image: My data is saved way:]

**And My Problem :** 
My code is written for the return of children

```
var parentCategory = Context.HierarchyBOMs
            .AsQueryable()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        var childCategoryQuery = Context.HierarchyBOMs
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(x => x.Level.GetAncestor(1) == parentCategory.Level);

        var childList = childCategoryQuery.ToList();
```

But this code only returns one child.

**How can all children be returned?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `IsDescendantOf`.

```cs
var childCategoryQuery = Context.HierarchyBOMs
    .Where(x => x.Level.IsDescendantOf(parentCategory.Level));
```